# PySpark - Directory printed as column in DF

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

On HDFS, I have my directories like this

hdfs://hostname/data/feed/data/dt=20180909/hour=04/uk/customer1'

In my script, I've pulled all the info from the files, but I also need to capture the location in the output dataframe. The only place this is stored is in the directory path (e.g. above = uk)

Is there a way to extract this to form part of the df output in a new column?

ALSO,

I have the below statement in my Pyspark code.

the issue is, when I do like("%i...) it thinks it's looking for an integer variable - same issues apply with %g

I've tried escaping the character with a \ but that doesn't work.

If I change all words to start with a 'b', the problem doesn't exist. So it is down to this issue.

Does anyone know how I may escape this problem?

```
    .withColumn('cleanapn',\
    sqlfunc.when(df4.apnstr.like("%info%"), "Info")\
    .when(df4.apnstr.like("%books%"), "Books")\
    .when(df4.apnstr.like("%interest%"), "Interest")\
    .when(df4.apnstr.like("%gonefishing%"), "Gonefishing")\
    .otherwise("Other"))\
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part of your issue can be easily solved with using `wholeTextFiles` api which gives tuple of (filename, file contents) which you can use to extract location info.

for example :

```
rdd1 = sc.wholeTextFiles("/data/feed/data/dt=20180909/hour=04/uk/customer1/")
```

will give you rdd1 as -

```
("/data/feed/data/dt=20180909/hour=04/uk/customer1/file1.txt","<data-in-file1.txt>")
("/data/feed/data/dt=20180909/hour=04/uk/customer1/file2.txt","<data-in-file2.txt>")
```

this you can manipulate to get dataframe of `DataFrame[location: string, data: string]` as -

```
df = rdd1 \
       .map(lambda x : (x[0].split("/")[-2],x[1]))\
       .toDF(['location','data'])
```

this should ideally give  ,

```
('uk',"<data-in-file1.txt>")
('uk',""<data-in-file2.txt>")
```

regarding, your second issue, I dont think there is anything wrong with usng %i or %g, you have to include specific error that you are getting.